# Using Hyperledger Composer REST Server multiuser without passport

Tags: rest, server, passport.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Is there possibility to enable the multiuser mode for the REST server without using passport?

I don´t see the reason to use the passport authentification in my use case, because the restrictions from the acl file should be enough and passport would just make the whole process of the use case unnecessarily more complex.

Yet I can´t find any options for that.

Thanks in advance for any hints or help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MultiUser mode of the REST server requires that Authentication is enabled with a passport strategy.

It is the Authentication that identifies each user individually so that Multi-User can separate users and enforce the ACL.

The examples and Tutorials show using GitHub as an example Passport Strategy, but Passport is a Framework and you can choose a different Strategy, or implement your own custom strategy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.So the REST server does not implement an authentification via ID Card, like in the playground or the regular access like during the deployment process?

Comment: The REST server DOES implement ID Cards when run in Multiuser Mode.  The ID cards are stored by the REST server and you don't see them on the file system.  You login using passport, then you can import Cards that only the logged in (passport) user can see.  I would suggest testing the REST server in multiuser mode to see how it works: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-multiuser.html